# Windows 7 PC cannot reboot unless powered down for at least 2 minutes

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot

My ageing (late 2009) Windows 7 desktop PC has started doing something odd of late. If I restart it, or shut it down completely, it does not restart properly - it gets up to the black screen with 'Starting Windows' at the bottom, but the Windows logo animation does not begin.

However, if I leave it powered down for at least 2 minutes (1 minute is apparently not enough), then on my next attempt it seems to always boot without any problems.

I tried booting it in safe mode when it wasn't working, and it gets as far as loading 'classpnp.sys' - which from a bit of online research, often suggests a problem with the HDD, but I ran CHKDSK and got no errors.

Although it's getting on for 6 years old now, it's not been used that heavily.

Specs:
- motherboard: ASRock G31M-S
- CPU: Intel Core 2 Quad Q8200 with integrated graphics
- RAM: 4GB DDR2
- HDD: 500GB Maxtor (from memory, I think just a basic 5400 RPM)

Comment: My bet would be your HDD is dying. Lack of errors from chkdsk means little.

Comment: Ah, I feared as much... is this likely even if the PC always seems to boot okay after a 2 minute power-off?

Comment: Yes. It could be the drive has an over-temp sensor that's kicking in, or the drive motor is failing and it's not spinning up fast enough. Either way I would make a backup ASAP if you have irreplaceable data on it.

Comment: Use a program like DiskCheckup that can read the SMART status of the drive and post the info here.

Comment: @CareyGregory There's no valuable data on it (all my files are on Dropbox), just the pain of re-installing Windows etc. (which I've only just done this week!) Might take the opportunity to upgrade to SSD and try to clone the drive...

Comment: @Bigbio2002 I will run DiskCheckup and report back, unfortunately I'm away from that PC until Monday morning (UK), so it will have to wait a bit...

Comment: Okay, so I've installed a brand new SSD drive (Samsung 850 EVO 120GB) and disconnected the old HDD entirely.

Installed Windows 7 fresh, and various software and updates.

Seemed to be working fine all day (including several reboots while installing software), until I get the same problem - trying to restart ater some Windows updates have installed, it boots up to 'Starting Windows' and hangs. 

Repeatedly switched off and rebooted - same result.

Switched it off and left for 2 minutes before switching back on - boots fine.

So if it's not the SSD, what else could it be? Motherboard? PSU? Fan?